# Does MSAL version 5.0.0 support Android 14 API 34?

Tags: android, msal

When I use MSAL 5.0.0, my Intune application cannot be started.
My Intune application supports API 34, and it works ok on Android 14 without MSAL.

My Intune application with API 33 supported has worked well with MSAL 4.10.0.

Could you please help me know if there is anything I need to do in my Intune application with MSAL 5.0.0?